# Add Scrollbar with TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add Scrollbar with TextFormField but when I scroll down I get an error. My Code

```
Scrollbar(
                child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 4,
                  minLines: 1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    isDense: true // text form first
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4743y.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not add any Scrollbar but it will be Scrollable.

```
Container(
          height: 60,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15,top: 10),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                minLines: 1,
                maxLines: 5,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54,)
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  isDense: true 
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: But I want to show scroll when I scroll down

Comment: I also search for it but i did not find it.